# How to kill msvsmon.exe when finished remote debugging?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, debugging, dynamics-crm, remote-debugging

We are a .NET LOB shop using MS CRM as our CRM platform. To this end, we many times a day during development phases are using remote debugging due to 2 connection limit to the server.

We are able to setup remote debugging without logging onto the machine by using PsExec. This works great - but how the heck do we kill the remote debugger for that user, once we are finished debugging?

In fact, not even sure how to kill the remote debugger in general, even when manually opening it... without remoting into server and using task manager, or keeping the server open and doing File->Exit on the debugger. Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found out I should be using the remote debugger service for this.. Thanks though for the reply

Answer (score 3):

I've never had much luck with remote debugging.  Whenever I'm debugging my plugins I usually work with the [PluginDebugger tool](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/MSCRMPluginDebugger) over at codeplex which allows you to debug locally on your machine by establishing a connection to the CRM server.  While this isn't the answer you were looking for, it's something to consider.

Comment: Thanks - we are using the debugger tool, but there's no replacement for the real deal so far. Thanks for the info - I'm going to try using the remote debugger service to solve this issue